# Website works locally but GitHub Pages show an empty page

Tags: github-pages

I have an issue which I was trying to solve for last few days. Here is my simple website repo: https://github.com/Jurek33/Robo_Friends . Here is the whole story:

1. I created a website locally using create react app.
2. I put it into my new github repo and followed the documentation to publish it using github pages.
3. It used to work fine before I decided to make some changes in a few files and push them to the repo.
4. After that I have noticed that changes do not apply on github pages and I still see the same website as before.
5. I figured out that I have 2 branches (master and gh-pages). Then I realized that I have beed applying all the changes to master branch but my website was publishing from gh-pages branch source. So I switch the source to master branch and deleted gh-pages branch
6. Since then it does not upload an html file and I only see an empty page. On a screenshot there are an errors I see on a console

Here are the soultions I already tried but they did not work for me:

1. Choosing a Jekyll theme (on some forums people say that it could be a problem even if the website does not use Jekyll)
2. Putting an html file into main folder
3. Changing github pages source (no matter what source I choose it is still not working)
4. Changing an html file path
5. Deleting an old repository and putting all local files into a new repository
6. Cleaning chrome browser cache

If someone knows what am I doing wrong and why I get this errors please let me know what is it. I will appreciate any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBDA2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved when I found this resource (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom ) and figured out that I need to install gh-pages package which creates gh-pages branch in my github repo and follow the instructions.